# How are the assassins from the first three games related to Desmond?

Tags: assassins-creed

I want to know how the assassins from the first three games are related to Desmond. I've tried to find it on the Assassin's Creed Wiki without success.

Answer (score 4):

Altaïr Ibn-La'Ahad (*Assassin's Creed*) is an ancestor to Desmond Miles through the maternal line.

The Auditore family (*Assassin's Creed 2*) and the Kenway family (*Assassin's Creed 3* and *4*) intertwined to become common ancestors to Desmond Miles through the paternal line.

Since you mentioned the wiki, you can find this information in the [Desmond Miles article](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Desmond_Miles#Ancestry) under "Ancestry".